# What kind of solver should I use in matlab when solving the optimization problem?

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to replicate a paper. In the paper,there are several optimization problems. I wonder what kind of solver should be used in Matlab coding.

For example, one problem goes like this:

$$min \sum_{t=1}^T((\sum_{i=1}^{S}\delta^{-t}\pi_{ts}({\beta_0+\beta_1r_s+\beta_2r_s^2+\beta_3tr_s+\beta_4tr_s^2}))-1)^2$$

where $r_s,\pi_{ts},T,S$ is given. The goal of the optimaztion problem is to find $\beta$ and $\delta$.
The constraints are:
$$\beta_0>0$$
$$\delta\in(0,1]$$
${\beta_0+\beta_1r_s+\beta_2r_s^2+\beta_3tr_s+\beta_4tr_s^2}>0$ for all $s\in(1,...,S)$ and $t\in(1,...,T)$ 
$$A\beta+B\delta>C$$
$A,B,C$ is a given matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function named "fmincon" which solves the non-linear optimization with non-linear constraints problems.